# PHP: polish national signs in $_POST - strlen and mb_strlen wrong values

Tags: php, post, utf-8, substr

i'm in desperate now cause i tried everything i found and still can't get results that i need very quickly cause i promissed to correct friend's website.

here's the problem:

i get a characters string via $_POST and it needs to be:

1. cleaned from any html tags (i do it through strip_tags : works good)
2. then, it needs to be exactly 1000 characters long and here where my pain begins: it must work with multi-byte characters such as Polish signs.

right now i tried to cut the text with:

- mb_substr($this,0,1000,'UTF-8')
- mb_substr($this,0,1000)

and

- substr($this,0,10000)

and i always get wrong results: the final string is always shorter than 1000 characters and i don't know why. can you help me with this one?

Maybe this will be usefull:

The text i paste to the form is:

```
Ciekawy, nieco sportowy wygląd, nisko zamontowana kanapa, dobre hamulce, niezłe podwozie, znakomita zwrotność, dynamiczny silnik – oto cechy którymi GS500E zdobywał rynek i pokonywał rywali w testach porównawczych. W 1992 r. postawiono go nawet do konfrontacji z większą Yamahą XJ600S Diversion i nowocześniejszym Kawasaki GPZ500S. Co prawda przegrał, ale też nie było szans, by walczył jak równy z równym. Ważniejsze były oceny, które wystawili mu dziennikarze z prasy fachowej. Zaskoczeniem było przede wszystkim to, że tak tani motocykl może prezentować tak wysoki poziom w zakresie mocy i charakterystyki silnika. Chwalono również hamulce i podwozie. W drugiej połowie lat dziewięćdziesiątych GS500E zaczął wyraźnie przegrywać w testach porównawczych. Nie mógł już dotrzymać kroku zupełnie nowym konstrukcjom pokroju Hondy CB500 czy Kawasaki ER-5. Nadal cieszy się jednak zainteresowaniem nabywców a jako motocykl o bardzo uniwersalnym charakterze trafia zarówno w ręce początkujących jaki i doświadczonych motocyklistów.
```

then i wnt to cut it to max 1000 characters:

```
$ok_to_go_to_database = mb_substr( strip_tags($long_text) ,0,1000);
```

and in this case it gives me back 931 characters :/

Comment: Well, is the incoming string *longer* than 1000 characters?

Comment: hi Pekka, it's always shorter: i don't know what counts in as those additional signs :/ , if i copy and paste a 1613 characters long text to the form, mb_strlen shows this length: 1733 and if i cut it with mb_substr($this,0,1000) all i get is only first 929 characters - i'm confused

Comment: What do the headers say the incoming charset is?

Comment: hi Ignacio, the page is set to work as UTF-8, but if you meant the charset of the string itself - i don't know how to check it

Comment: sorry Pekka: you asked about incoming string: yes, it's longer than 1000

Comment: You could try a really horrible workaround like `substr(mb_convert_encoding($str,"UTF-8","UCS-4"),0,4000)` and then convert it back.

Comment: I can't reproduce: http://codepad.viper-7.com/RUHDEw

Comment: hey : so i pasted it there, and it has even different length: 951. by the way i check the lengths here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/charcount.shtml

Comment: i'll try that terrible thing, thanks

Comment: Works fine for me ? http://codepad.viper-7.com/f8q8Ab

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> len(u'Ciekawy, nieco sportowy wygląd, nisko zamontowana kanapa, dobre hamulce, niezłe podwozie, znakomita zwrotność, dynamiczny silnik – oto cechy którymi GS500E zdobywał rynek i pokonywał rywali w testach porównawczych. W 1992 r. postawiono go nawet do konfrontacji z większą Yamahą XJ600S Diversion i nowocześniejszym Kawasaki GPZ500S. Co prawda przegrał, ale też nie było szans, by walczył jak równy z równym. Ważniejsze były oceny, które wystawili mu dziennikarze z prasy fachowej. Zaskoczeniem było przede wszystkim to, że tak tani motocykl może prezentować tak wysoki poziom w zakresie mocy i charakterystyki silnika. Chwalono również hamulce i podwozie. W drugiej połowie lat dziewięćdziesiątych GS500E zaczął wyraźnie przegrywać w testach porównawczych. Nie mógł już dotrzymać kroku zupełnie nowym konstrukcjom pokroju Hondy CB500 czy Kawasaki ER-5. Nadal cieszy się jednak zainteresowaniem nabywców a jako motocykl o bardzo uniwersalnym charakterze trafia zarówno w ręce początkujących jaki i doświadczonych motocyklistów.'.encode('cp1250').decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
929
```

And the CRLF makes 931.

[**Check your HTTP headers. Make sure that you are really receiving data in UTF-8 and not CP1250.**](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset)

Comment: THANKS Friends! Have new things to think about here now. yes - the lengths indeed are correct in strlen, will work on this, have a best year, lots of $, girls and weed :)